# Multidependent drop down list Google Sheets not working

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have macro in Apps Script , which supposed to do multidependent drop down list in Google Sheets, but it is not working.

Script:

```
function Test() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bezposr = ss.getSheetByName("Koszty bezpośrednie");
  var dane = ss.getSheetByName("Dane");
  var actCell = bezposr.getActiveCell()

    if(actCell.getColumn()== 3 && actCell.getRow() >5) {
      var makes = dane.getRange(1,1,dane.getSheetId(),dane.getLastColumn()).getValues();

      var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(actCell.getValue())+1;

      var validationRange= dane.getRange(2,makeIndex,dane.getlastrow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      actCell.offset(0,1).setDataValidation(validationRule)}
};
```

When I turn on macro nothing is happening. Validation rule for cells is not applied in sheet 'Koszty bezpośrednie'.

Could you please take a look and advise what I should change to make this script work? Maybe whole script is written incorrectly, I've done it with youtube.com tutorials

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

To react to a change in a dropdown cell, the function needs to run on a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

I am highlighting one issue below, but correcting that issue will not make the code work. The code in the question should really be completely rewritten.

```js
var makes = dane.getRange(1,1,dane.getSheetId(),dane.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

The third parameter to [Sheet.getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) is supposed to be a positive integer that represents the number of rows to retrieve. The code does not work because it does not get an integer. The [Sheet.getSheetId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetid) method gets a longish text string that looks like `H-RQclaE1saF8-83NSPZK8iGH2bxY_BbgYInoL_FAlA3`.

There are many dependent dropdown solutions out there, such as my [dependentDropDownLists_](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/160451/269219) script. You may find it easier to use one of those tried and tested solutions instead of coding your own from scratch.